# Is there any way in css I can get chatbubble without using transform?

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to get chat bubble like Ios .I am trying to use  `-webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);` But in old browser like xulrunner and SWTbrowser this css instruction does not work properly on those browser Though it works on all recent browser.below is my css and HTML

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

section {
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 50px auto;
 
}
 div {
    max-width: 255px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
  }

.clear {
  clear: both
}

.from-me {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #5ca9db;
  border-radius: 12px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 56px;
  }
  
  .from-me:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -7px;
  height: 20px;
  border-right: 20px solid #5ca9db;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 16px 14px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
} 
.from-me:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -56px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
}
.from-them {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  background: #f2f3f5;
  border-radius: 12px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 56px;
}

.from-them:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -7px;
  height: 20px;
  border-left: 20px solid #f2f3f5;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px 14px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
}

.from-them:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="from-me">
    <p>Hey there!What's up?!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  
</section>
<section>
  <div class="from-them">
    <p>Hey there!What's up?!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  
</section>
```

Though on chrome it gives correct output but same does not work on old browser like SWT browser and XULrunner. Below the output I got in those browser.

[image]

Here as I said `-webkit-transform: translate` is not giving proper result in these browser.Any pointer to achieve same without `-webkit-transform: translate` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purposes, since you are using `absolute` positioning, then `translate` is equivalent to corresponding `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` values. Just add the values from translate into them, and you should get something along the lines:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

section {
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 50px auto;
 
}
 div {
    max-width: 255px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
  }

.clear {
  clear: both
}

.from-me {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #5ca9db;
  border-radius: 12px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 56px;
  }
  
  .from-me:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -7px;
  height: 20px;
  border-right: 20px solid #5ca9db;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 16px 14px;  
} 
.from-me:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -26px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.from-them {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  background: #f2f3f5;
  border-radius: 12px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 56px;
}

.from-them:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -7px;
  height: 20px;
  border-left: 20px solid #f2f3f5;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px 14px;
}

.from-them:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -26px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="from-me">
    <p>Hey there!What's up?!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  
</section>
<section>
  <div class="from-them">
    <p>Hey there!What's up?!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to adjust the look a little bit but you can use a triangle without any transforms. Here are a couple examples.

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
.bubble1, .bubble2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  background-color: #5e98d6;
  position: relative;
  }
  
.bubble1:after {
  content:'';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 15px 15px 0;
  border-color: transparent #5e98d6 transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top:100%;
}

.bubble2:after {
  content:'';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0 0 15px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #5e98d6;
  position: absolute;
  left:100%;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble1"></div>

<div class="bubble2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I Could able to get traingle but We have some constrain to have other look rather then Triangle

Comment: I am upvoting you for the answer i will try to see if i can accomodate this

Comment: @Rajesh  Yeah, it's pretty bulletproof since its only using element borders so it should support most browsers. You could always use a feature detect to get it as a fallback...  `@supports (transform: translate){ //pretty styling}`